# Open circuit fault detection using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, detection, fault, terminal

I was able to implement short circuit fault detection of under ground cables and I was also able to add a GSM module(SIM900D) with it.

I'm trying to further enhance my project by detecting open circuit fault detection.

It seems a bit difficult as I can't extract any useful information from and open terminal (V=0 and I=0 because of the open terminal.)

I tried searching online and found 2 relevant papers that use an RC meter to count the time constant to find the open circuit location.

The circuit diagram and code are given in the link of pdf. The links are given below:

[OPENCIRCUIT & SHORT CIRCUIT CABLE FAULT DETECTION USING ARDUINO](https://ijcrt.org/papers/IJCRT1705466.pdf)

[OPEN CIRCUITED UNDERGROUND CABLE DISTANCE LOCATOR](http://www.iraj.in/journal/journal_file/journal_pdf/1-487-15359695149-13.pdf)

[Here is the link to the RC meter.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/CapacitanceMeter)

The problem is that when I generate an open circuit across the charging resistor and change its resistance both the time constant and capacitance change while keeping the resistor constant so it's not really useful for open circuit fault detection.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong or how I can implement this differently to get an accurate result?

Here is the pic of my simulation:

[image]

Comment: There is an image upload button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: You won't get accurate results.  The methods suggested are prototype concepts.  None of the linked papers actually goes out and measures cables with the developed tools.  The capacitance method will probably work, but you'd need to calibrate it to the cable type and the conditions (the surrounding conduits and other conductors.)  Keep in mind that you're not going to get results accurate to the centimeter or even to the meter with this kind of setup.  You might be able to tell within a few meters of where the break is.

Comment: The range of the detector will also be limited - it uses only the the charge current available from the digital output pin.  Long cables will have high(er) capacitance and a lot of leakage current.  Longer cables will mean a much longer charge time.  At some length, the Arduino won't be able to build up a significant charge on the cable - the open circuit detector will simply wait forever (or a timeout) for the voltage to rise.

Comment: This type of detection calls for time domain reflectometry, usually. Which is *way* more complex than that. Cable capacitance varies with everything so it's not a reliable indication

Comment: Even if there are limitations is it possible to get the desired outcome of finding it within the small distance that you talked about?? If so what modification does my circuit need??